# smallest element in a array of strings c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm

I am trying to find the smallest element in a array of strings but I can't figure out how to do this. I came up with this code idea which works perfectly for *integers* but does not work for strings. This will compile, although it only checks the first character in string for its ASCII value. In other words, in an array of strings: `lists[5] = { "aaa", "z", "cccc", "tt", "jjj"};` *lists[1]* or *"z"* is the smallest element of the strings. However, because 'a' is a lower ASCII value the code will print out `Smallest aaa` instead of `Smallest z`. Now I know I could do some kind of deep compassion of each character in the string using .length but I want to use something that is simple that can solve this because I want to add it to a function that will be overloaded to a integer so I can go back and forth between string and integer comparisons. But if this is not possible I will just have two separate functions to handle each.

What if any suggestions do you have on how to find the smallest element in a array of strings?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {


string  lists[5] = { "aaa", "z", "cccc", "tt", "jjj"};
    string smallests;
    smallests = lists[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << smallests << endl;
        if (lists[i] < smallests){   // Flip < to > to find largest
            smallests = lists[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Smallest " << smallests << endl;
    cout << *min_element(lists, lists + 5) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Smallest as in length? Or by alphabetical order?

Comment: Well, length but I can now see that alphabetical order would come in play. As in string  lists[5] = { "a", "z", "c", "t", "j"}; would all be the same length. But one thing at a time because that check would be the code I have now haha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to note that [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) can be passed a custom comparison function. So, let's define what it means to be smallest.

From the comments, it appears that you want shorter strings, and then to sort them lexicographically.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool smallest(std::string const & lhs, std::string const & rhs) {
    if (lhs.size() < rhs.size())
        return true;
    if (lhs.size() == rhs.size() && lhs < rhs)
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::string lists[5] = { "aaa", "z", "cccc", "tt", "jjj"};
    std::cout << *std::min_element(lists, lists + 5, smallest) << "\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
z
```

Answer (score -3):

The < operator wont work on strings in C. You need to use strcmp provided by string.h

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/string_h.htm

Your code to compare then becomes:

```
if (strcmp(lists[i], smallests) < 0) {
    smallests = lists[i];
}
```

Comment: This is C++. `operator<` is very defined.

Comment: this is C++, and string class HAVE < operator (list is of type string)